# Search Multiple date ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Multiple date picker with Wordpress advanced custom field. When I save data, I got something like

```
a:6:{i:0;s:10:"2018-12-23";i:1;s:10:"2018-12-30";i:2;s:10:"2019-01-11";i:3;s:10:"2019-01-16";i:4;s:10:"2019-01-25";i:5;s:10:"2019-01-31";}
```

from wp_postmeta table. How can I query/search specific date?

Comment: ACF doesn't natively support a datepicker that has a 'multiple/range' feature. What are you using for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the output wrapped inside [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).